# Yii2 - port a request to a controller based on user types

Tags: php, yii2, acl

I have a controller as `admin` and another as `guest`.
I want to have some `http` requests to a static address like `test.com/guest/index`, and have this results:

if the user(determined in request body as a `username`) is an `admin` (actually `not-guest`) user then it should port the request(not redirect, because redirect cant be done in an api-client, and of course http request cant move along the methods on redirect) to a specific method of `admin` controller.

like i send a `POST` request to `test.com/guest/index` and I am `admin` so it should run the `methodName()` - I should specify the name not the request - from `admin` controller and if somebody else who is not `admin` send the same request it should run `methodName()` (same method name) from `guest` controller.

how can this be done? I use Yii2. so I want to know is there any way to do this or if there is no way so is it possible in a single controller with different method names?
is it possible in ACL extension?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating single controller named `GuestController` and process request not based on sent information, but on current user status:

```
class GuestController extends yii\web\Controller {
    public function actionIndex() {
        $response = null;

        $model = User::getByCredentials();

        if (!$model) {
            $response = $this->guestAction();
        } else {

          switch ($model->role) {
            case 'admin':
               $response = $this->adminAction();
               break;
            case 'user':
               $response = $this->someUserAction();
               break;
          }
       }

        echo $response;
    }

    protected function adminAction() {
        $data = \Yii::$app->request->post(); // still can access _POST/_GET...

        return 'Hallo Warold!';
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

---

```
/**
 *
 */
class User extends yii\web\ActiveRecord {
    public funcion getByCredentials($username, $password) {
        $model = self::findOne(['username' => $username]);

        if (!empty($model) && \Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $model->password)) {
            return $model;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this looks a good approach but how should I set \Yii::$app->user->role part? because there is no login functionality only based on request body and username, where should I config it?

Comment: Well, if you don't allow users to login, than I don't think there should be processing of admin function. I can pass any information to your form - username also.

Comment: actually username and password will send along the request. I should validate them and if it was an admin then do methodAdmin() and if not do methodGuest(). so in each request it should do the login itself there is no session or cookie or other things. is there any way to do this?

Comment: @mohammadfallah.rasoulnejad Check update. You simply have `role` as user attribute in DB, than get user by username from database and compare password. If found and matches password - proceed with access-by-rule, else process as guest.